# How to use messageKeyGenerator in StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor

Tags: spring-retry

I am trying implement sample retry mechanism for RabbitMQ using Spring's StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.

As stated in documentation, I need to setup message key generator as the message id is absent. What I don't understand is the real usage of unique id generated per message. i.e. when I used below implementation I did not have any issue with retry:

```
StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor = 
RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
           .maxAttempts(3)
           .backOffOptions(2000, 1, 2000)
           .messageKeyGenerator(
            new MessageKeyGenerator() {
              @Override
              public Object getKey(Message message) {
                return 1;
              }
           );
container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] {interceptor});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stateful retry needs the originating message to be somehow unique - so the retry "state" for the message can be determined - the simplest way is to have the message publisher add a unique message id header.

However, it's possible something in your message body or some other header might be used to uniquely identify the message. Enter the `MessageKeyGenerator` which is used to determine the unique id.

Using a constant (1 in your case) won't work because every message has the same message key and will all be considered to be deliveries of the same message (from a retry perspective).

The framework does provide a `MissingMessageIdAdvice` which can provide limited support for stateful retry (if added to the advice chain before the retry advice). It adds a messageId to the incoming message.

"Limited" means full stateful retry support is not available - only one redelivery attempt is allowed.

If the redelivery fails, the message is rejected which causes it to be discarded or routed to the DLX/DLQ if so configured. In all cases the "temporary" state is removed from the cache.

Generally, if full retry support is needed and there is no `messageId` property and there is no way to generate a unique key with a `MessageKeyGenerator`, I would recommend using stateless retry.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for your answer. I can generate unique id per message using MessageKeyGenerator. But, I wanted to test if retry works if same id is used for all messages and I found that retry is working for all messages. So, I still dont understand need for unique id. Can you please help? Thanks again.

Comment: You won't have a problem if the container concurrency is `== 1` because each delivery will happen on the same thread and the retries will be exhausted for one message before the next is processed. As soon as you increase the concurrency, multiple messages will be delivered on different threads. If they all have the same message key, retry won't work properly. A successful delivery will reset the state so a bad message will be retried more times than expected.

Comment: Thanks Gary, got it now :)
Cheers.